# How do I increase the size of windows preview from dock on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

If I right click on a application on the dock, all windows, I see windows previews. I can even set to see then by default using:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'previews'
```

But, anyway they are too small. I would like to have bigger previews.

How to change its size?

Using Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to increase the preview in dock, but [Dash to Panel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/) has the feature.

Comment: @pomsky you mean you can increase the size arbitrary  on dash to panel or dash to panel has bigger previews?

Comment: Dash to Panel lets you change the size of the preview: https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-x3UAjjdTJvk/Wv1aMw6_MAI/AAAAAAAAAjs/P4kRZkCLr74B_9uN9t_s8o2tcGC6AgG4ACLcBGAs/s1600/dash_to_panel_gnome_shell_extension_previews_height.png

Comment: @pomsky how did you get this menu on your print sccreen

Comment: It's Dash to Panel's configuration window.

Answer (score 0):

I've been wanting to dig into this issue for a while now and finally found the time today. I tried Dash to Panel but didn't like it that much. So I've create a patch for Dash to dock (which is Ubuntu Dock) to make the preview size configurable: https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock/pull/1454